# Causal Impact Analysis Error ValueError("{point} not present in input data index.".format( ValueError: 20201019 not present in input data index

Tags: python, yfinance

I am a beginner trying to run a simple Causal Impact analysis on some stock data. However, everytime I try to plot the impact graph I get a Value error which is below:

raise ValueError("{point} not present in input data index.".format(
ValueError: 20201019 not present in input data index.

It's stating that it can't find the above date in my data index even though when I print the dataframe index the date is clearly there. I have tried everything I can find online and in the documentation without any luck, so I am at a lose to what to do next. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import yfinance as yf
from causalimpact import CausalImpact
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller

training_start = '2020-09-01'
training_end = '2020-10-19'
treatment_start = '2020-10-20'
treatment_end = '2020-10-23'
end_stock = '2020-10-24'

y = ['BTC-USD']
y = yf.download(tickers = y,
                start = training_start,
                end = end_stock,
                interval = '1d')
y = y['Adj Close'].rename('y')

stocks = ['ZAL.DE', 'SQ', 'CRSP', 'JD', 'DE', 'KTOS', 'GOOG', 'TPB']
x = yf.download(tickers = stocks,
                start = training_start,
                end = end_stock,
                interval = '1d')
x = x.iloc[:,:len(stocks)]

x.columns = x.columns.droplevel()

x.index = x.index.tz_localize(None)

df = pd.concat([y,x], axis=1).dropna()

df_training = df[df.index <= training_end]

test = adfuller(x = df_training.y)[1]

if test < 0.05:
    print('The time series is stationary')
else:
    print('The time series is not stationary')

differencing = df_training.pct_change().dropna()

test = adfuller(x = differencing.y)[1]

if test < 0.05:
    print('The time series is stationary')
else:
    print('The time series is not stationary')


plt.figure(figsize = (8,6))
sns.set(font_scale = 1.2)
sns.heatmap(differencing.corr(),
            annot = True,
            fmt = '.1g',
            cmap = 'YlOrBr',
            center =  True,
            linewidth = 1,
            linecolor = 'black')
#plt.show()

df_final = df.drop(columns = ['ZAL.DE'])


df_final = df.set_index(pd.date_range(start='2020-09-01', periods=len(df_final.index)))
pre_period = [pd.to_datetime(training_start), pd.to_datetime(training_end)]
post_period = [pd.to_datetime(treatment_start), pd.to_datetime(treatment_end)]

impact = CausalImpact(data=df_final, pre_period=pre_period, post_period=post_period)
impact.plot()


ERROR MESSAGE:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MGerdes\PycharmProjects\EconometricsCausalInference\Google Causal Impact.py", line 71, in <module>
    impact = CausalImpact(data=df_final, pre_period=pre_period, post_period=post_period)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MGerdes\PycharmProjects\EconometricsCausalInference\server\Lib\site-packages\causalimpact\main.py", line 206, in __init__
    processed_input = cidata.process_input_data(data, pre_period, post_period,
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MGerdes\PycharmProjects\EconometricsCausalInference\server\Lib\site-packages\causalimpact\data.py", line 120, in process_input_data
    pre_data, post_data = process_pre_post_data(fmt_data, pre_period, post_period)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MGerdes\PycharmProjects\EconometricsCausalInference\server\Lib\site-packages\causalimpact\data.py", line 266, in process_pre_post_data
    checked_pre_period = process_period(pre_period, data)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MGerdes\PycharmProjects\EconometricsCausalInference\server\Lib\site-packages\causalimpact\data.py", line 389, in process_period
    raise ValueError("{point} not present in input data index.".format(
ValueError: 20201019 not present in input data index.
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: @MichaelButscher the full traceback has been added, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just change the date training_end. the data has no "2020-10-19", maybe there are no data in 2020-10-19

Comment: "Maybe there are no data in..." is a suggestion and not an answer to the question. This should rather be posted as a comment. Once you earn 50 reputation you'll be able to do that.